# Get field type in annotation processor

Tags: java, kotlin, annotations, annotation-processing

I've got an interface, whose fields are annotated. I'm trying to get field's type in Annotation Processor, in this case "Boolean"

```kotlin
interface Test {
    @CustomAnnotation
    var someField: Boolean
}
```

Annotated element has kind `METHOD` in processor, name `getSomeField` and return type `void`. Where can I get actual field's type?